# Wordpress altering a link

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My problem is really simple.
Wordpress has been configurated with www.giudicelli-jahn.com as the home and site URL; database is OK; file itself is ok.

My homepage contains a link written directly in HTML, like this

```
<a style="display:block" href="http://www.giudicelli-jahn.com/category/droit-des-etrangers/">
```

However, strangely, Wordpress transforms the URL and adds its original directory sites/, the result is this

```
<a style="display:block" href="http://sites/www.giudicelli-jahn.com/category/droit-des-etrangers/">
```

I understand that it comes from the fact that the website is not located in the root or public_html directories but in a **sites/** directory, however I have no idea why Wordpress changes the link or how to change it.

Does anyone have any idea? It does so with a couple of images and links, all of which are directly written in the wordpress php files.

Here's the link: http://www.giudicelli-jahn.com/

You can see for example on the homepage that an image isn't loading, because it's looking for the wrong URL (even though the URL on the file itself is correct...)

Thanks a lot for your help,

Cheers.

Comment: Just to clarify - the folder 'sites' is inside your webroot folder?

Comment: Nope, it's inside the root folder. So sites/ is not inside public_html/ !
I was wondering if it could be a problem, but then again everything else works. The only links that are not functioning are those that are written directly in the php files (and thus not managed by the wordpress CMS).

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of your current database and replace all

http://sites/www.giudicelli-jahn.com/

with

http://www.giudicelli-jahn.com/

Then drop your current database or create a new the import the updated database(if you create a new database update your wp-config.php file with new database details)

Comment: I just checked my database and there are no occurrences of sites/www.giudicelli-jahn... I had already replaced everything there was to replace so I really don't see where this comes from.